# Count total marks and set rank using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with two columns first for userId & second for marks

`+-------+-------+
| UserId | Marks |
+--------+-------+
|      1 |   20  |
|      1 |   20  |
|      3 |   15  |
|      1 |   30  |
|      3 |   20  |
|      4 |   25  |
+--------+-------+`

I want to count marks of particalur user and then give rank like 1st or 2nd With userId

`+-------+-------+
| UserId | Rank  |
+--------+-------+
|      1 |   1   |
|      3 |   2   |
|      4 |   3   |
+--------+-------+`

I have two queries one for Counting marks and second for getting rank but don't know how to combine that both queries and get result like

Queries are :

count total :

> SELECT UserId, SUM(Marks) AS total FROM result GROUP BY UserId

Get Rank :

> ( SELECT UserId, Marks, FIND_IN_SET( Marks, ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( Marks ORDER BY Marks DESC ) FROM result ) ) AS rank FROM result ) ORDER BY  `rank` ASC

Comment: I see that you want to `COUNT` the column but you use `SUM`...

Comment: No, I want to `count` marks of particular student.